# how to set env variables in my CMD script

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following entryfile

```
FROM <image-of-nodejs>

COPY docker/node/entry.sh /var/entries/entry.sh
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ant -y
CMD ["/var/entries/entry.sh"]
```

the image is used by a docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  my_node:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/node/Dockerfile-build-dev
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./
        target: /var/proj
```

and the entry.sh file is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
export QNAMAKER_SUB_KEY=b13615t
```

If I then start the image and I enter the docker, I won't find my env variable set:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate -d
docker-compose run my_node bash

root@9c081bedde65:/# echo ${QNAMAKER_SUB_KEY}

<empty>
```

I would prefer to set my variables throug my script in place of the `ENV` Dockerfile command. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, `docker-compose run` doesn't run a command inside the container you started with `docker-compose up`.  It starts a *new* container to run a one-off command.  You probably want `docker-compose exec`.

The reason you don't see the variable when using `docker-compose run` is that you are overriding your `CMD` by providing a new command (`bash`) on the `docker-compose run` command line.

You could consider:

- Using `ENV` statements in your `Dockerfile`.
- Using the `environment` key in your `docker-compose.yml`

The former will embed the information into your image, while the latter would mean that the variable would be unset if you didn't explicitly set it in your `docker-compose.yaml` file (or using `-e` on the `docker run` command line).

You may be able to accomplish your goal using an `ENTRYPOINT` script and setting the value there, but that won't impact the environment visible to you when using `docker exec` (or `docker-compose exec`).